# Checking session in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my web application i am checking session state like this.. in page load even of one of the page but it is every time session is not null is showing see this is my code...

```
if (Session["my"] != null)
{
  Response.Write("hi");
}
else
{
  Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```

this is the page where i am assigning value to the session like this i am taking 
one button and one link button and write the code like this

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["my"] = "surya";
    Response.Redirect("default1.aspx");
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("default1.aspx");
}
```

but every time it is showing i mean even i click on link button it is showing "hi" message
can u help me is there any ispostback problem is there

Comment: Learn to use punctuation please!

Answer (score 1):

It is normal because you assign a value to the session variable "my" and in default.aspx you write "hi" if the session variable "my" is not null.

Just change the line

```
Response.Write("hi");
```

to

```
Response.Write(Session["my"].ToString());
```

and you will see the value of session variable "my".

Answer (score 1):

What if you add another button and click handler:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session.Abandon();
   Response.Redirect("default1.aspx");
}
```

I expect the session to be cleared then, so that that "Hi" is not printed.

What happened (I guess) is that you put something in the session and never cleared it.

**Note**: that `Session.Abandon()` clears the entire session. You could also use `Session.Remove("my");` to clear just this value.

Answer (score 0):

**Page Load is executed each time the page is requested**

Which is why (when your session != null) "Hi" is being printed on the screen.  Are you just wanting this to happen once?

If so explore [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Will only happen if its not a postback
        // (first request)
    }
}
```

Comment: @m.edmondson i want to check if session is empty it is redirect the default.aspx.if session contain value "hi" message should display

Comment: @Surya - You are redirecting to another page on postback (default1.aspx) are you sure this isn't the page you're seeing "Hi" on?

Comment: @m.edmondson i am assigning session value in button and not in link button and redirecting to default1.aspx page where i am checking session if it is empty redirect to default.aspx page if session value is

Comment: @Surya - Almost certainly its because you've clicked it already.  Its getting assigned a value, so from that point onwards (until the session expires) it will print "Hi".  Have you put a breakpoint on to check this?

Comment: @Surya - So is it because you have previously assigned "Hi" to the session?